# Rails help SyntaxError in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get this error in view:

```
SyntaxError in PublicController#fast

C:/Rails/konkurranceportalen/app/controllers/public_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
@titel => 'Heading'
         ^\
```

My action in my controller:

```
def fast
render :template => 'kategoris/show', :layout => 'kategori'
@titel => 'Heading'
@konkurrancers = Konkurrancer.where('type', 'nyhedsbrev')
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want `@titel = 'Heading'`. `=>` is for building `Hash`es, as in `foo = {:a => 1, :b => "bar"}